Water shutoff turns off water only to part of the house
I had an emergency today due to washer supply valve breaking. The hot water flooded the room very quickly until I pulled the inlet valve to water heater.
According to our home inspection report, there are two shutoff valves as seen below  
They are both on the same pipe, so I assume they are redundancies. When I tried to turn them off, the bottom one turned only 1/8 turn and came to a full stop, whereas the top one was fully open and took several full turns to a stop.
Thinking that I had now turned off water to the whole house, I tested all the faucets. The water was off everywhere except in the kitchen. I let the kitchen faucet run for several minutes and it was showing no signs of slowing down. There is no whole house shutoff under the sink.
Is it possible that my water supply first comes to the kitchen faucet before going to the main shut off valve? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having a main water shutoff.
I had to call the city to turn off water at the meter since the plumber won't come until the evening. We just bought this house so we are learning

The main water shut off should be close to where the water comes into the house.  The valve that turns only 1/8 probably does not work, so the second one was added.

Look near the water meter.

There should be a shut off outside near the meter for use by the utility (and you with a meter key). Then, fix your inside shutoff. I prefer quarter turn ball valves for reliability long term.
